# How to listen the Alert box of WebPage clicked in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am now developing a Chrome extension that can record the webpage's alert or confirm box clicked.
What I want is when the alert box was clicked, the extension can capture the event.

I can not find related document about it, so turn here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods:

1. override those functions inside a [page context script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)
2. use [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) with [Page.javascriptDialogClosed](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-javascriptDialogClosed) event listener